# How to custom message response error code when validation invalid in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem about validation in Yii 2.

Basically to custom message of validation in Yii, we use to structure after

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'required', 'message' => 'anything']
    ];
}
```

But, now how I can replace "message" to "code"? I want to response code when data invalid?

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name'], 'required', 'code' => 1001]
    ];
}
```

Any help, thank you.

Comment: [['name'], 'required', 'message' => '1001']

Comment: Thank your feedback, But I want to replace message => code

Comment: there is no attribute 'code' in model rules.if you create custom validation you  can return number or string.so directly pass your code in message.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much, Yasin Patel :)